# Why does Cert-C prohibit assignments within a while loop declaration?

Tags: c

Say I want to loop through a list in C. There are two usual ways I can do this.

```
/* method a */
while (ptr = ptr->next) { /* do stuff */ }
```

or

```
/* method b */
ptr = head;
while (ptr) { /* do stuff */ ptr = ptr->next; }
```

[CERT-C bans method A](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP45-C.+Do+not+perform+assignments+in+selection+statements). Why is this? Surely B requires more manual coding to remember to iterate at all possible loop points  (maybe the function needs to `continue` past some nodes if they're invalid) and method A guarantees consistent iteration.

Comment: The risk assessment says: "Errors of omission can result in unintended program flow."

Comment: "because doing so typically indicates programmer error and can result in unexpected behavior."

Comment: They even give a list of allowed exceptions, `while ((ptr = ptr->next) != 0)` appears to be fine, as does `while ((ptr = ptr->next))`.

Comment: The explanation "indicates programmer error" doesn't explain much to me. Neither does "errors of omission", since I'm perfectly aware of the assignment that is happening. I was hoping to find an example on the page that provided a security reason why. Besides, the parenthesis workaround still opens me up to an assignment vs comparator mistake.

Comment: It says in your link "...it is frequently a case of the programmer mistakenly using the assignment operator = instead of the equals operator ==. Consequently, many compilers will warn about this condition..." Are you looking for something more?

Comment: There was an [attempted backdoor in Linux](https://freedom-to-tinker.com/2013/10/09/the-linux-backdoor-attempt-of-2003/) which eploited `=` vs `==`. So *this* is why it says to avoid `=` in the `while` condition... Sure there are some legit use cases, but it can easily be a symptom of a hard-to-diagnose error with big consequences.

Comment: Now that's a reason!

Comment: I think `for (; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)`. The intent is clear that way.

Answer (score 2):

Assignments, using the `=` operator, can be easily confused with the equality `==` operator. This is clearly shown by this part of the text:

> Although the intent of the code may be to assign `b` to `a` and test the value of the result for equality to `0`, it is frequently a case of the programmer mistakenly using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equals operator `==`.

I agree that in the case of the `while` loop - where you expect that each loop takes the next element - this element of surprise is not really present for accomplished coders. For new coders it may still wrong foot-them. Either they mistake the assignment for testing equality or they don't directly see when the result of the expression is `0`.

---

I'd make sure the expression is written `while (ptr != NULL)` because that way the intent is most clear, and the expression doesn't have any side effects. You could use `while ((ptr = ptr->next) != NULL)` if you do allow a single side effect within selection statements (I prefer the term "flow control statements" myself, but that's more Java-like).

I'd myself stay away from the additional parentheses as in `while ((ptr = ptr->next))` as that may be mistaken for sloppiness and code beautifiers may warn against the unnecessary parentheses.